# How to measure the divergence of a signal from a specific value

Tags: matlab, signals, signal-processing

I have a signal and I want to measure its divergence from a specific value.

Is there a Matlab function to do that?

[image]

This is a sample of my signals 
and I want to know how far this signal from a DC value of 1 V

Comment: Maybe you can clarify the question a bit more? How do you define "divergence from a specific value"? Divergence is a mathematical term, but it applies to a vector field.

Comment: Ok, I have different signals and a DC value. I just want to measure which signal is more close and which one is more diverge from this DC value

Comment: You mean "difference" then? You can use `-` in MATLAB to subtract the DC value from your signal.

Comment: SB, I think you need to provide a small data sets to represent signals and dc value. I cannot imagine you just wanted to subtract the signal and DC

Comment: As CL implied, divergence = signal - 1. You do not really need a function, just simple subtraction. (you could do other things like calculating the mean or range of divergence after that, but that's a follow on topic

Comment: I add a picture of one of my signal, and I want to measure its divergence from a DC value of 1. Does the difference is enough to give us a correct idea for the divergence of the signal from the default value

Answer (score 1):

This seems like you should do a one-sample t-test. Try

```
[h,p,ci,stats] = ttest(signal-1)
```

Comment: it looks good, but could you give more details, what each outcome means

Comment: if h= 1 means null hypothesis is rejected (signal diff from 1), p is p value, ci is confidence interval, and stats are stats.  The MATLAB help on ttest gives a more complete discussion

Comment: @SerwanBamerni, click accepted answer if this is what you needed.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using a non parameteric test (like ranksum) on the absolute values of the deviation from 1. Since you want to check which of two signals deviates more from the dc:

```
[p,h] = ranksum(abs(signal1 - 1), abs(signal2 -1))
```